# When using "Controller as" syntax, what "scope" is the controller instance property published into?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

The documentation for [`Controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) says:

> The controller instance can be published into a scope property by specifying ng-controller="as propertyName".

What is the `scope` that controller instance is published into? Where does that scope come from? Where can I learn more about this "scope"?

**EDIT:**

Part of my question is, if you don't use controller as, and instead inject $scope...and then set up your properties on $scope...how does it get from there to the scope that's in the view? Essentially the controller instance right?

Comment: basically you need to read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: yes, I'll post an answer with bit explaination

Comment: It's the same scope as without the controllerAs syntax, if that's your question.

Comment: Thanks zeroflagL. I was pretty sure already it was the same scope.

Comment: I guess part of my question is, if you don't use controller as, and instead inject $scope...and then set up your properties on $scope...how does it get from there to the scope that's in the view? Essentially the controller instance right?

Comment: The scope that's in the view *is* the scope injected in the controller. The only difference, with controllerAs, is that the controller itself is stored in that scope.

Comment: @JB Nizet...how can that be? If I don't inject it into the controller, I can still bind to properties on the controller instance via controller as.

Comment: Yes, because controllerAs puts the controller itself in the scope. So when you write {{ myCtrl.foo }}, it gets myCtrl from the scope, and foo from myCtrl.

Comment: Ok so then injecting the $scope into the controller just gives you access to the scope from within the controller? Vs controller as which instead reverses it and gives you access to the controller from the $scope in the view?

Comment: Yes, injecting the scope allows you to access the scope from within the controller function. But controllerAs doesn't "reverse" it. All it does is adding the controller to the scope. You can still inject the scope into the controller, even with controllerAs. See this slightly modified example from the angular documentation: http://plnkr.co/edit/bTDutaL4jQrHrBFWNjPb?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-controller` creates a child scope whether you use `controllerAs` or not. A child scope prototypically inherits from its parent.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  {{$id}} - the outer scope id is 1 (same as root here)
  <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    {{$id}} - the child scope id is 2
  </div>
</div>
```

The `FooCtrl` instance will get the child scope that was created by the `ng-controller` directive:

```
.controller("FooCtrl", function($scope){
   console.log($scope.$id); // 2
});
```

`controllerAs` doesn't do anything about the scope instance that `ng-controller` creates. All it does is it simply assigns the controller instance on the scope of the controller (the child scope created by `ng-controller`) under the `as alias` property

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl as ctrl">
  {{ctrl.p1.v}}
</div>
```

that the controller function assigns onto the instance:

```
.controller("FooCtrl", function($scope){
   this.p1 = {v: "p1"};

   // the following is true
   console.log($scope.ctrl === this); 
   // but don't do this, since the controller function shouldn't know about ctrl alias

});
```

Comment: I didn't realize the controller was added to the scope *before* its constructor function was even invoked. JavaScript is sooo strange...

Comment: @JBNizet, I know, it's kinda unintuitive...(I had to check to make sure) :) but I think it's because they create an instance first with `Object.create` and only later calling the constructor function.

Comment: @JBNizet, yeah, in fact they do: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0-rc.0/src/ng/controller.js#L117

Comment: Ok that's a big help. So if it prototypically inherits, then I could directly access a property on the parent scope if the child scope doesn't have a property of it's own with the same name, correct? And I could do that with $scope.variableOnTheParent. Yes?

Comment: @richard, yes, but if you assign a value to that property, then it would shadow the one on the parent scope. This, btw, has little to do with controllers - the same is true even if you had a child scope created by another directive, like `ng-if`. Also, avoid making assumptions about the alias - it's only known in the View. Also, scope inheritance seems to be an anti-pattern of inter-controller communication (although, I haven't seen a fully compelling alternative - some use `$broadcast`/`$on`, so go with pure directive model, some use services)

Comment: Ok thanks. I wouldn't ever do it, just wanted to make sure it was what I understood as prototypical inheritance. This is all just javascript. :-)